# Encapsulate complex mysql inserts with back quotes

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I have exported some sql statements, and now need to replay them. The issue arises when I play this to mysql where actual java code is included in the VALUES. This code includes back slashes, quotes, double quotes - sometimes causing mysql to mis-interpret escaping and quoting:

```
INSERT INTO sonar.snapshot_sources(ID, SNAPSHOT_ID, DATA) VALUES (267, 420, 
'package com.company.gateway.dl.util    
"((\''|\")*)(stuff|moreStuff)((\''|\")*):((\''|\")*)([0-9]+)((\''|\")*)";
');
```

Above is not the full text, but the quoted bit here, cause the insert to fail. A work around is to enclose the complex text value in back quotes, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO sonar.snapshot_sources(ID, SNAPSHOT_ID, DATA) VALUES (267, 420, 
`'package com.company.gateway.dl.util
"((\''|\")*)(stuff|moreStuff)((\''|\")*):((\''|\")*)([0-9]+)((\''|\")*)"; 
'`);
```

The question I have is, how can I sed precisely these statements to add back quotes to encapsulate where required? I want to replace 'package  with `'package and '); with '`); The closing bracket seems the most complicated since many more statements will match this.

Comment: write it all to a `tmp` file and read it with a db option that loads a file? Even that may be difficult. Good luck!

Comment: I have 7000 of these. And 1.5 million other insert.

Comment: What are you doing with this part `\''`of the regex ?

Answer (score 0):

The below python script can help you. The script will read the sql dump file and add backtick to the matched regex and prints it to output file. Input file and output file should be given as a commandline argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import re
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Provide input and output file to begin processing')
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    if not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
        print('Input file does not exit')
        sys.exit(1)

ifile = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

# Compiling the regex
rex = re.compile(r"""(INSERT[\s\S]+?)('package[\s\S]+?')(\);)""")

# Reading the file as a string
dataFile = open(ifile, 'r').read()
fp = open(ofile, 'w')

# Substituting it
print(re.sub(rex, r'\1`\2`\3', dataFile), end='', file=fp)

fp.close()
```

Output

```
INSERT INTO sonar.snapshot_sources(ID, SNAPSHOT_ID, DATA) VALUES (267, 420, 
`'package com.company.gateway.dl.util    
"((\''|\")*)(stuff|moreStuff)((\''|\")*):((\''|\")*)([0-9]+)((\''|\")*)";
'`);
```